# Data dump for the month of March 2012

Tags: support, status-completed, data-dump

Is there going to be a data-dump on ClearBits for the month of March 2012?

The last one was in December 2011, and the one before that in September 2011, so according to that schedule, the next one should have been in March 2012.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, we are currently working out a [new arrangement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127891/2) for our data dumps to be hosted at *[Public Data Sets](http://aws.amazon.com/publicdatasets/)* on [Amazon Web Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services) (AWS). At the moment, the ClearBits method of uploading files for hosting a torrent is broken. We'll keep you posted here on Meta Stack Overflow and on [the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/) after we have a final answer on where it will live.

Comment: Any update on this, Geoff?

Comment: We are still working on getting the attention of the right people at Amazon.  It's harder than you might expect.

Comment: The data dump [as of 2012-03-31 is now available](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133862/when-will-quarterly-data-dumps-resume/133991#133991).