# When will quarterly data dumps resume?

Tags: support, status-completed, data-dump

According to this blog article dated Sept 2011:  https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/creative-commons-data-dump-sep-11/

> While we will always continue to produce Stack Exchange creative commons data dumps, we are moving to a quarterly schedule for all future dumps.

Clearbits, the recommended site to get the data dump torrents at http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump, lists the most recent dump as December 2011.

Is the plan still to provide quarterly data dumps?

If so, when will they resume?

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but closely related: [Data dump for the month of March 2012](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128128/131713)

Comment: I liked it better when they were monthly.  I don't see why this couldn't be done on a more frequent basis.

Comment: 6-8 weeks should be the canonical answer.

Comment: As of January 2013, the last dump is from August 2012 --- which increase the delay to *24 weeks or more*.

Comment: The Stack Exchange Data Dump is now at the Internet Archive, located here: [Stack Exchange Data Dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange).

Answer (score 14):

**Update**

According this blog article dated Jan 2014: ["Stack Exchange Creative Commons data now hosted by the Internet Archive"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-cc-data-now-hosted-by-the-internet-archive/)

> The Stack Exchange Data Dump is at the Internet Archive, located here: [Stack Exchange Data Dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange).

*(The clearbits link no longer works.)*

---

<strike>We have been in a holding pattern with Amazon which have promised us space for our public data dumps.  Due to their lack of response I will be uploading [Q1 2012](http://www.clearbits.net/torrents/2017-apr-2012) [to ClearBits](http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump) which should be available within the next few hours.</strike>

Comment: Thank you for providing a one-off data dump.  While that is helpful, it does not directly address the question posed.

Comment: THe last dump on ClearBits is from August 2012, now we are are in January 2013 and I cannot find any new dump. Where can we find them?

Comment: We are still in the process of determining our new home for data dumps.   Don't worry, we haven't forgotten.

Comment: [Happy one-year anniversary! :-)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117178/can-the-stack-exchange-data-dump-be-provided-as-a-public-data-set-on-amazon-web/127891#127891)

Comment: @PatJames now with the new host for the dumps it should be a full answer that you can accept. :)

Comment: @GeoffDalgas, I updated this post with the new location of the data dump. I thought you might be particularly interested since you answered, it's your job, etc... Thanks

Comment: @sorin note that I've updated this answer to reflect the new home for the data dumps.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Happy two-year anniversary! :-)