# Am I really a pundit?

Tags: support, comment-voting, comment-badges

I've just been awarded the [Pundit](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/94/pundit) bage!  Whooo, go me (didn't even realise it existed)!  =D

I'm curious to know which of my (all rather mundane) comments has brought for me such honour.

I found [Can I view a list of my “great comments”, perhaps in my profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130908/161492), which suggests using [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66765/my-most-popular-comments).  However, that query shows that I have only 2 comments with a score of 5 or more and I can't see anything wrong with the query...

Do I not deserve this shiny new badge?  :(

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the API to view your up-to-date comments:

> `http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/<youruseridnumberhere>/comments?sort=votes&min=5`

I think there may be a new syntax for the 2.0 version of the API, but this still works for the time being.  Go to your profile to get your user ID number (in the upper right hand box), it's not just your username.

This works for this site, but change "meta.stackoverflow.com" to "stackoverflow.com" or "physics.stackexchange.com", etc. for the other sites.

---

As has been mentioned in the comments, with the (*long* ago) deprecation of that version of the API and with the ever-fresh SEDE data, it's much more effective to do the search on there (e.g., https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/166532/how-close-am-i-to-pundit-badge).

Comment: Excellent - thank you!  I only had to remove `meta.` from the URI as I'm interested in my SO not MSO profile.  But otherwise, that's great.

Comment: @eggyal Yeah, sorry I wasn't sure which site, but it works for all of them, just change the name of the site.

Comment: Could you update this for the latest syntax? It's not working for me dispute multiple attempts at guessing what it might be now.

Comment: @martineau It's still working for me, what is the syntax that you are using.  Make sure and use your Meta ID (which can be found on your profile in the upper right corner).

Comment: I tried http://stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/355230/comments?sort=votes&min=5 and get a **Page Not Found**, so instead I used [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/27196/my-top-ranked-comments) which I got from another question.

Comment: @martineau You need the `api.` in front of everything.

Comment: http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/355230/comments?sort=votes&min=5

Comment: When I use http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/355230/comments?sort=votes&min=5 I get what looks like a correct response, but it's displayed as raw XML.

Comment: It's JSON.  Chrome can read it natively, but you may need a plugin for other browsers.  It gives you all of the dirty details, it doesn't just spit back a count, unfortunately.

Comment: Nor does it have links to the comments or related question or answer.

Comment: The upside is that it's current, the data dump from the other link you referenced is getting close to 6 months old already.

Comment: Yeah, it's a little old, but it works and has links in the output (which is extremely useful & convenient). If I save the XML response from your query to an `.xml`. file and then open that in Firefox I get an **XML Parsing Error: not well-formed** message.

Comment: The latest update on SEDE was on June 26th, the API will get you at least up to the hour updates.  It's not an XML formatted block that it returns.  It is [JSON](http://www.json.org/).  Search "parse JSON in <your fav language>" on SO and it should come up with some libraries that are available.

Comment: Yeah, just realized it's JSON not XLM myself. OK, I'll see what I can do with Python where it's handled by a built-in I believe -- thanks.

Answer (score 6):

As [the comments on the answer to that question ultimately resolve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130906/can-i-view-a-list-of-my-great-comments-perhaps-in-my-profile/130908#comment360313_130908), the data dump used by the Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE) is only updated periodically. The SEDE doesn't work on *live* data.

If you've done a lot of commenting *recently*, then it's very likely that the data dump does not contain all of your recent comments. And those are the ones that earned you the Pundit badge.

If the comments don't appear in the current data dump, then [you'll have to use the API, as jonsca's answer suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133884/153008). Or just wait until the next data dump is released, and then run your query again.

Related: [When will quarterly data dumps resume?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133862/when-will-quarterly-data-dumps-resume)

Answer (score 0):

Use the updated 2.x API tester here:
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments-on-users

Just put your user id in the `ids` text box. Find your user id by navigating to your Stack Overflow profile and looking at the URL in your browser.